Prioritize /filter data being fetched from UNION queries
I have the below data sample from the below query where I have two UNIONed queries. What I want to do from the overarching query I want to exclude records where the same ITEM_NUMBER and SUBINVENTORY_CODE exist in the 2nd Query that is in the 1st Query AND where the INV_LOCATOR for the record in the 2nd Query has the value 'AAAAAAA'. I have tried doing this by way of using an analytical window function with ROW_NUMBER but I admittingly not seeing how I need to change it to set the ROW_NUMBER value appropriately and then filter on it in the outermost query.
This is my current results based on the below query:
ITEM_NUMBER SUBINVENTORY_CODE   INV_LOCATOR     QUERY       IVT_SEQNUM  PRIORITY    OVERALL_PRIORITY
12923       41OPR               Z-B-01-02-C     1st Query   1           1           1
12923       41OPR               W-130-00-00-00  1st Query   2           1           2
12923       11OPR               AAAAAAA         2nd Query   1           2           1
12923       41OPR               AAAAAAA         2nd Query   1           2           1

Desired Results:
ITEM_NUMBER SUBINVENTORY_CODE   INV_LOCATOR     QUERY       IVT_SEQNUM  PRIORITY    OVERALL_PRIORITY
12923       41OPR               Z-B-01-02-C     1st Query   1           1           1
12923       41OPR               W-130-00-00-00  1st Query   2           1           2
12923       11OPR               AAAAAAA         2nd Query   1           2           1

As you can see in the Desired results we have excluded the last record from the '2nd Query' row because it contains the INV_LOCATOR value of AAAAAAA AND this same ITEM_NUMBER and SUBINVENTORY_CODE combination already exist in the resultset of the '1st Query'
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT item_number, subinventory_code, INV_LOCATOR, QUERY, ivt_seqnum, priority, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY priority, item_number, 
subinventory_code  ORDER BY priority DESC, priority) Overall_Priority 
  
  FROM
(SELECT ESI.item_number,  IOQD.subinventory_code  SUBINVENTORY_CODE, 

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ESI.item_number , IOQD.subinventory_code  
ORDER BY ESI.item_number, IOQD.subinventory_code ) ivt_seqnum
               
 ,LOC.SEGMENT1||'-'||LOC.SEGMENT2||'-'||LOC.SEGMENT3||'-'||LOC.SEGMENT4||'-'||LOC.SEGMENT5 INV_LOCATOR, 1 as priority, '1st Query' AS QUERY 
 
FROM egp_system_items ESI, inv_onhand_quantities_detail IOQD, inv_item_locations LOC
WHERE ESI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 100000110904412
AND ioqd.subinventory_code = '41OPR'
AND IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id    
AND LOC.inventory_location_id = ioqd.locator_id

UNION ALL
      
SELECT ESI.item_number, decode(substr(IOQD.secondary_inventory,1,3),                                
                                                              
                                                              ,'41O','41OPR'                                                                  
                                                              ,IOQD.secondary_inventory) subinventory_code, 

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ESI.item_number , IOQD.secondary_inventory  
ORDER BY ESI.item_number, IOQD.secondary_inventory ) ivt_seqnum , 
               
case when 
 (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_item_loc_defaults iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.locator_id       = iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum= 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 ) is not null 
then (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_item_loc_defaults iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.locator_id       = iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum= 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 )     
 
Else 'AAAAAAA'
END as      INV_LOCATOR   , 2 as priority  , '2nd Query' AS QUERY       
               
FROM egp_system_items ESI, INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES IOQD 
WHERE IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id    
AND ESI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 100000110904412

) --WHERE (priority <> 2 AND INV_LOCATOR <> 'AAAAAAA') 
) 

EDIT
I've added the additional analytical function named cnt_first_query and attempted filtering on it in the outer query, but it now only fetches 1 row, the 3rd row below for '11OPR' and 'AAAAAAA'
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT item_number, subinventory_code, INV_LOCATOR, QUERY, ivt_seqnum, priority, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY  priority, subinventory_code  ORDER BY  priority, subinventory_code  ) Overall_Priority 
  ,COUNT(CASE WHEN priority = 1 THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY item_number, subinventory_code) as cnt_first_query
  FROM
(SELECT ESI.item_number,  IOQD.subinventory_code  SUBINVENTORY_CODE, 

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ESI.item_number , IOQD.subinventory_code  
ORDER BY ESI.item_number, IOQD.subinventory_code ) ivt_seqnum
               
 ,LOC.SEGMENT1||'-'||LOC.SEGMENT2||'-'||LOC.SEGMENT3||'-'||LOC.SEGMENT4||'-'||LOC.SEGMENT5 INV_LOCATOR, 1 as priority, '1st Query' AS QUERY            --, ioqd.locator_id
 
 
 
FROM egp_system_items ESI, inv_onhand_quantities_detail IOQD, inv_item_locations LOC
WHERE ESI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 100000110904412
AND ioqd.subinventory_code = '41OPR'
AND IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
and IOQD.organization_id = esi.organization_id
AND LOC.inventory_location_id = ioqd.locator_id

UNION ALL



SELECT ESI.item_number, decode(substr(IOQD.secondary_inventory,1,3),                                  
                                                              '11C','11CCL'
                                                              ,'11O','11OPR'
                                                              ,'18O','18OPR'
                                                              ,'41S','24000'
                                                              ,'41O','41OPR'
                                                              ,'60O','60OPR'
                                                              ,'70O','70OPR'
                                                              ,'70C','70CCL'
                                                              ,'70M', '70OPR'
                                                              ,IOQD.secondary_inventory) subinventory_code, 

ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ESI.item_number , IOQD.secondary_inventory  
ORDER BY ESI.item_number, IOQD.secondary_inventory ) ivt_seqnum , 
               
case when 
 (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_item_loc_defaults iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.locator_id       = iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum= 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 ) is not null 
then (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_item_loc_defaults iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.locator_id       = iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum= 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 )   

when (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_secondary_locators iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.SECONDARY_LOCATOR= iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum = 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 ) is not null 
        Then (SELECT iil.SEGMENT1||'-'||iil.SEGMENT2||'-'||iil.SEGMENT3||'-'||iil.SEGMENT4||'-'||iil.SEGMENT5
           FROM inv_secondary_locators iild, 
                inv_item_locations iil
          WHERE iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
            AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
            AND iild.SECONDARY_LOCATOR= iil.inventory_location_id
            AND rownum = 1 and length(Segment1) >= 1 )

Else 'AAAAAAA'
END as      INV_LOCATOR   , 2 as priority  , '2nd Query' AS QUERY  
               
FROM egp_system_items ESI, INV_ITEM_SUB_INVENTORIES IOQD --,  inv_item_loc_defaults iild, inv_item_locations iil
WHERE IOQD.inventory_item_id = ESI.inventory_item_id
AND IOQD.organization_id = ESI.organization_id
AND ESI.INVENTORY_ITEM_ID = 100000110904412
--AND iild.inventory_item_id = esi.inventory_item_id
--AND iild.subinventory_code = IOQD.secondary_inventory
--AND iild.locator_id  = iil.inventory_location_id 

) --WHERE (priority <> 2 AND INV_LOCATOR <> 'AAAAAAA') 
)    --WHERE (INV_LOCATOR <> 'AAAAAAA' AND OVERALL_PRIORITY <=1)


WHERE NOT cnt_first_query > 0 AND INV_LOCATOR = 'AAAAAAA'


Please read : [mre] and Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example, even for a very simple SQL query?

Could you please add sample input data as well?

Since you already have 1st and 2nd query flag within your unioned data - you could use Row_Number() Over() analytic function not in your union query but later using the 1st/2nd flag in Order By part of Row_Number() and in outer query's Where clause with Case expression. You can keep your IVT_SEQNUM column, though, but there will be another Row_Number() column that will be used as the filter in the outer query's Where clause ...
You could declare a CTE with your union sql code ...
WITH
  your_union_sql_data AS
     -- put your union sql below - resulting as the first table from the question
    ( Select   12923 as ITEM_NUMBER, '41OPR' as SUBINVENTORY_CODE, 'Z-B-01-02-C' as INV_LOCATOR, '1st Query' as QUERY, 1 as IVT_SEQNUM,  1 as PRIORITY, 1 as OVERALL_PRIORITY From Dual Union All 
      Select   12923, '41OPR', 'W-130-00-00-00', '1st Query', 2, 1, 2 From Dual Union All
      Select   12923, '11OPR', 'AAAAAAA',        '2nd Query', 1, 2, 1 From Dual Union All 
      Select   12923, '41OPR', 'AAAAAAA',        '2nd Query', 1, 2, 1 From Dual
    )

... and  use 1st/2nd query flag to order the rows for numbering ...
--      M a i n    S Q L : 
SELECT   ITEM_NUMBER, SUBINVENTORY_CODE, INV_LOCATOR, QUERY, IVT_SEQNUM, PRIORITY, OVERALL_PRIORITY
FROM   ( Select    a.*, 
                   Row_Number() Over(Partition By ITEM_NUMBER, SUBINVENTORY_CODE 
                                Order By ITEM_NUMBER, QUERY, SUBINVENTORY_CODE) as RN_ITEM_SUBINV 
         From      your_union_sql_data  a
       )
WHERE  RN_ITEM_SUBINV = Case When INV_LOCATOR = 'AAAAAAA' And QUERY = '2nd Query'
                             Then 1
                        Else RN_ITEM_SUBINV
                        End
ORDER BY  ITEM_NUMBER, QUERY, SUBINVENTORY_CODE

R e s u l t :



ITEM_NUMBER
SUBINVENTORY_CODE
INV_LOCATOR
QUERY
IVT_SEQNUM
PRIORITY
OVERALL_PRIORITY




12923
41OPR
Z-B-01-02-C
1st Query
1
1
1


12923
41OPR
W-130-00-00-00
1st Query
2
1
2


12923
11OPR
AAAAAAA
2nd Query
1
2
1



fiddle
